# Remapping doctrine columns to match with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I wanna use FOSUserBundle with the already existing users table. The problem however is that my table has different column names than FOSUserBundle. For instance, I have `"login"` column, while the bundle required `"username"` field.

Besides, I have to remove `"salt"` column, as I want to use only the hashing function (required functionality).

Could you please explain me step-by-step how to do that? Or give me some hints at least? Documentation says just a couple of sentences from which I understand nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/doctrine.md#replacing-the-mapping-of-the-bundle) is quite clear about what you need to do:

1) Your user class needs to extend `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` but I think it's already the case.

2) You need to redefine the mapping for the whole class (eg with Doctrine2 ORM: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine/model/User.orm.xml)

3) You can change and remove the mapping for the fields you don't want (unless required by the Bundle)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the column name in some override attributes to the mapping of your child class like so..

`YAML`

```
// Acme\UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\User.orm.yml
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    ...
    attributeOverride:
        username:
            column: login
            type: string
            length: 255
```

For more about this see the doctrine [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

This will map the column `login` to the parameter `username`.